# Setup Ansible host for WSL (1 and 2) Windows 10

Tags: windows, ansible, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I see a lot of information about the opposite (i.e. how to use WSL as the server to configure Windows using winrm), but I can't find any info about actually configuring a WSL (1 and 2) using ansible in another machine.

My setup is as follows:

- Server machine orchestrating Ansible in a Ubuntu Server 18.04
- Host machine running WSL 1 and WST 2 instances in Windows 10

Using the following for `hosts.yml`:

```
all:
  children:
    desktops:
      hosts:
        wsl:
          ansible_host: 192.168.1.204
          ansible_user: my-windows-user
```

I get the following output (at least it can understand there is a machine there):

```
> ansible wsl -m ping                                                                                                                                                                     

wsl | UNREACHABLE! => {
    "changed": false,
    "msg": "Authentication or permission failure. In some cases, you may have been able to authenticate and did not have permissions on the target directory. Consider changing the remote tmp path in ansible.cfg to a path rooted in \"/tmp\". Failed command was: ( umask 77 && mkdir -p \"` echo ~/.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-1574712678.8429368-151724391009763 `\" && echo ansible-tmp-1574712678.8429368-151724391009763=\"` echo ~/.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-1574712678.8429368-151724391009763 `\" ), exited with result 1",
    "unreachable": true
}
```

This happens both for WSL 1 and WSL 2 instances. Any ideas?

P.S. If the user/password for the WSL instance is wrong, then the output becomes (so there is some correct authentication going on here on some level):

```
wsl | UNREACHABLE! => {                                                                                                                                                                           
    "changed": false,                                                                                                                                                                                        
    "msg": "Invalid/incorrect password: Permission denied, please try again.",                                                                                                                               
    "unreachable": true                                                                                                                                                                                      
}
```

Answer (score 0):

By default WSL2 does not run services. To enable **systemd**, reboot after editing `/etc/wsl.conf` to include:

```ini
[boot]
systemd=true
```

Then proceed to install, enable and start the openssh-server package in your distro of choice.